# screen mode in portrait the orientation issue in samsung mobile

Tags: android

I'm developing custom camera application.I forced to set the screen-mode is Portrait.But come to samsung mobile the orientation of screen problem.What will do to set up application using portrait mode in samsung mobile

Comment: ...could you rephrase that?

Comment: No...I just set the  android:screenOrientation="portrait" in android manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
In your activity,

```
   /** Forces the application to run in portrait mode */
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

In your manifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name="yourActivityName"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
  </activity>
```

Also, if your application runs on v2.2 or above you can rotate camera orientation to portrait using camera.setDisplayOrientation(90).

Comment: Problem means? You are still in landscape mode or getting some errors?